# How do I always ignore a pattern in ZSH completion?

Tags: zsh

With the following in an empty directory:

```
$ zsh -d -f -i

% autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
% zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*:*' ignored-patterns foo
% mkdir foo
% mkdir bar
% mkdir zsh
```

- When I type `cd <TAB>` I get a menu with only `bar` and `zsh`. This is great.
- When I remove `zsh` and I do `cd <TAB>`, `bar` is completed without showing a menu. Also great.
- But when I remove `bar` as well and I do `cd <TAB>`, `foo` is completed. I don't want that to happen.
- Starting again, but from the parent directory and doing `cd <TAB>` to complete the parent directory and then `cd <TAB>` I see `foo` or get it completed for all three cases.

Is there a way to ignore `foo` completely so I never see it and never get it completed in the same directory and any other directory?

Edit:

I found that using `zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*:*' ignored-patterns '**/foo'` the problem of seeing the ignored pattern from a parent directory goes away, but ignored patterns are still completed when there is not other choice. So with this:

```
$ zsh -d -f -i

% autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
% zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*:*' ignored-patterns '**/foo'
% mkdir foo
```

and typing `cd <Tab>` still completes `foo`. Is there a way of just not completing in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason for this behavior

The zsh completion system has multiple completer functions. These are enabled via:

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' completer <list of completers>
```

The default value for this is `_complete _ignored` ([see](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Control-Functions-1)).

This means that first regular completion is tried, and if it did not produce a completion, the special `_ignored` completer is tried instead. The `_ignored` completer ignores the `ignored-patterns` style you defined and therefore finds the `foo` match.

From the [zsh documentationon on `_ignored`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fignored):

> The `ignored-patterns` style can be set to a list of patterns which are compared against possible completions; matching ones are removed. With this completer those matches can be reinstated, as if no `ignored-patterns` style were set. [...] The `single-ignored` style is also available as described above.

### A solution

Remove `_ignored` from the list of completers.

You can display the current list via `zstyle -L '*' completer`.
If this is empty, it still is at its default value and you can disable `_ignored` via:

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete
```

### A sort-of solution

From the [documentation entry on `single-ignored`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-single_002dignored_002c-completion-style) (mentioned in the citation above):

> This is used by the `_ignored` completer when there is only one match. If its value is ‘`show`’, the single match will be displayed but not inserted. If the value is ‘`menu`’, then the single match and the original string are both added as matches and menu completion is started, making it easy to select either of them.

So if you set it to `show` (or `menu`) (via `zstyle ':completion:*' single-ignored show`) then it won't immediately be completed and only show up in the tab completion menu.
This means you could just ignore it and continue typing.

### Appendix

It is (as far as I can tell) not possible to disable a completer only for `cd` (say with `zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*:*' completer ...`), as they are determined at the very beginning of the completion process.

There is also a way of ignoring certain file/directory patterns using the [`file-patterns` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) and the `^` glob pattern, but the style does not seem to be used with `cd` completion. But e.g. for `ls` this should do the trick:

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ls:*:*' file-patterns '^foo|^**/foo:directories'
```

The zsh guide on completion is also a good resource for all this:
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. Removing _ignored is super counterintuitive because of its name. It sounds like it would honour `ignored-patterns`, but actually it ignores them. It's like double negation. I also find the ZSH documentation very hard to understand, thanks for making sense of it!

Comment: Maybe "a completer that also completes previously `_ignored` completions".
But yea, the documentation really takes quite a while to understand.